# $f,g\in \mathscr{L}(E)$ $f\circ g=0$ and $f+g\in GL(E)$ with $dim(E)<\infty$, then $rank(f)+rank(g)=dim(E)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$f,g\in \mathscr{L}(E)$ $f\circ g=0$ and $f+g\in GL(E)$ with $dim(E)<\infty$, then $rank(f)+rank(g)=dim(E)$

My attempt

from $f\circ g=0$ wet get that $Im(g)\subset ker(f)$. from here I get two tracks:

1. show the other inclusion and use the rank-nullity theorem on $f$ then replace $ker(f)$ by $rank(g)$ to get the desired equality.
2. show that $ker(g)\subset Im(f)$ which implies that $\operatorname{null}(g)\leq rank(f)$ and gives us by adding $rank(g)$ to both sides $$dim(E)\leq rank(f)+rank(g)$$
   The other inequaliy comes from $Im(g)\subset ker(f)$.

Any Hint would be greatful.

Comment: There is an additional condition of $f$ and $g$ that you have so far ignored: $f + g$ is in $GL(E)$. What can you figure out from this?

Comment: thank you @PaulSinclair!!

Answer (score 1):

First note that $rg(f+g)\leq rg(f)+rg(g)$ :

Since $Im(f+g)\subset Im(f)+Im(g)$$$rg(f+g)=dim(Im(f+g))\leq dim (Im(f)+Im(g))=dim(Im(f))+dim(Im(g))-dim(Im(f)\cap Im(g))\leq dim(Im(f))+dim(Im(g))= rg(f)+rg(g) $$

And $f+g\in GL(E)$ gives us $rg(f+g)=dim(E)$, hence the inequality $$dim(E)\leq rg(f)+rg(g)$$

The other inequality follows from the inclusion $Im(g)\subset ker(f)$ and the rank-nullity theorem.